# ActionController::TestCase vs ActiveSupport::TestCase; What exactly is the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I assume that `ActionController::TestCase` is for only testing `ActionControllers`, but what does `ActiveSupport::TestCase` test? Does it test everything (models, views, and controllers)? Is one or both of these classes old/outdated? I think I prefer to stick with the stock RoR way of testing rather than getting more confused with other gems etc. I'm new to Ruby on Rails and TDD.

Comment: After more reading I am now assuming that `ActiveSupport::TestCase` is for testing the Model only, and `ActionController::TestCase` is for testing the Controller only? Is this correct? Also, it seems that `ActiveSupport::TestCase`s exist in `test/unit` directory, and `ActionController::TestCase`s exist in `test/functional` directory.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rails-sets-up-for-testing-from-the-word-go

Comment: if you have a look at the source you will see that ActionController::TestCase sets up test-requests etc for functional testing that you don't need for model tests etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActionController::TestCase is designed for testing controllers, so it has special methods for testing controllers.
ActiveSupport::TestCase is designed for testing models.
there is api for these classes
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TestCase.html

Comment: Not quite correct, as `ActiveSupport::TestCase` is implemented as base test class, so it not for 'models', but for tests. I mean you obviously can test controllers using `ActiveSupport::TestCase`. `ActionController::TestCase` just have some handy assertions and naming conventions that make test easier. For example byt default it will try to set up `@controller` variable by assuming you test is named after controller plus 'Test'.